# Adding control objects to radiobutton.controls makes them disappear on a windows form

Tags: c#, radio-button

I'm new to c#. I'm certain this problem is an easy fix and stupidly basic..but I just fail to google/msdn/ it out.

I'm trying to make a form with a radioButton and a textbox. When radiobutton is checked - textbox becomes available for editing. When radiobutton is unchecked - textbox gets blocked. Sort of an interface thing. That's the basic concept of the idea. However in future it's going to expand to groups of radiobuttons that control groups of textboxes, which makes it kinda boring to punch in a separate if-else with a hardcoded name of the textbox for every radiobutton...and thus I've decided to write some methods, which include this line:

```
radiobutton1.Controls.Add(textbox1);
```

and it appears that when I run my application - this line makes the textbox disappear. Can't figure out why.

Doing the same with Panel and textboxes doesn't seem to be a problem.
Here's an example of a code I'm trying my concept on. I've tested. My problem repeats here to.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton1.Controls.Add(textBox1);
        }
    }
}
```

[Resulting form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPSuZ.png)

Comment: How does adding a control to a radio button makes sense? Every control is a container control but that does not mean is sensible to use everywhere. You may want to look at [user controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0). So create a user control containing the radiobutton and the textbox.

Comment: The user control gets handy because you can also add logic to that so the problem you mention with hardcoded names here will solve itself because you would move that logic into the user control where there is only one radiobutton and one textbox. So easy to find.

Comment: thanks. I'll look into user controls thing as an alternative way of achieving my goal. 
Google didn't suggest trying it instead when I've asked him why my textbox or any other control object disappear. That's how being new to c# and googling works really. So it's easy to find when you know what you should have been looking for from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The base for all controls and even Forms is `Control`. This class has a lot of members that are not used in many controls derived from it. The `Controls` collection makes only sense in the case of container controls like Panels, FlowLayoutControls, Forms, etc.

But you can easily create your own control derived from `RadioButton`.

```cs
public class RadioButtonEx : RadioButton
{
    private TextBox _textBox;
    public TextBox TextBox
    {
        get => _textBox;
        set {
            _textBox = value;
            if (_textBox != null) {
                _textBox.Enabled = Checked;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCheckedChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCheckedChanged(e);
        if (TextBox != null) {
            TextBox.Enabled = Checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have added this class, compile your code. When you open a `Form` in the forms designer, you see this control appear in the Toolbox window and you can drag and drop it to you form as any other control.

Yoy will even notice that the new `TextBox` property appears in the Properties window under "Misc" where you can assign it a `TextBox`:
[image]

I.e., when using the `RadioButtonEx` , you don't need to do anything in code to make it work as expected. This is the power of .NET's Windows Forms. A great step forward compared the old style Visual Basic, VBA or Access forms.

Comment: Awesome. I've tested it and already figured out how I can implement and extend logic of my application based on your solution. tyvm.